# Assigning names to the list output of dplyr do operation

Tags: r, dplyr

The `do` function in the package **dplyr** usually produces the list. Is there are way to assign names to that list depending on the input to `do`? Specifically I pass the `group_by` result and would like that the names of the list would give some indication to what group the list elements correspond.

Here is the toy example of what I want to achieve:

```
> it = data.frame(ind=c("a","a","b","b","c"),var1=c(1,2,3,4,5), var1=c(2,3,4,2,2))
> group_by(it,ind)%.%summarise(min(var1))
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  ind min(var1)
1   c         5
2   b         3
3   a         1
```

Now do this with `do`

```
> do(group_by(it,ind),function(x)min(x[,"var1"]))
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

Ideally the names should be `c("c","b","a")`.

Is this possible? And why **dplyr** reverses sorting of the groups? Note in my case the result of the `do` operation is a `lm` object.

**Edit:** The comment asks for realistic example, here is what I had in mind. I fit models depending on the data (dummy code):

```
res <- do(group_by(data,Index),lm,formula=y~x)
```

Now I want to do various things like

```
sapply(res,coef)
```

So I want to relate the results to the original dataset, in this case to what `Index` the coefficients correspond.

**Edit 2:** The desired behaviour can be achieved with `dlply` function:

```
dlply(it,~ind,function(d)min(d[,"var1"]))

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 3

$c
[1] 5

attr(,"split_type")
[1] "data.frame"
attr(,"split_labels")
  ind
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

I am looking whether it is possible to replicate this behaviour with dplyr, preferably with minimal intervention.

Comment: You could also use `as.list(by(it, it$ind, function(x) min(x[,'var1'])))` to get what you want, no need for `dplyr`.

Comment: Oh I know lots of ways how to do that, but I'm asking specifically about dplyr.

Comment: @mpiktas why not post a more realistic example of a problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this marked up version of `do.grouped_df`:

```
do2 <- function (.data, .f, ...) {
    if (is.null(attr(.data, "indices"))) {
        .data <- dplyr:::grouped_df_impl(.data, attr(.data, "vars"), 
            attr(.data, "drop"))
    }
    index <- attr(.data, "indices")
    out <- vector("list", length(index))
    for (i in seq_along(index)) {
        subs <- .data[index[[i]] + 1L, , drop = FALSE]
        out[[i]] <- .f(subs, ...)
    }
    nms <- as.character(attr(.data, "labels")[[1]])
    setNames(out, nms)
}

library(gusbfn)

it %.% group_by(ind) %.% do2(function(x) min(x$var1))
```

which gives:

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 3

$c
[1] 5
```

It could also be combined with `fn$` from the gsubfn package like this to shorten it slightly:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gsubfn)

it %.% group_by(ind) %.% fn$do2(~ min(x$var1))
```

giving the same answer.

Comment: Thanks, apparently next version of **dplyr** will have more sophisticated version of `do`, which probably will include such behaviour: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/pull/283

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data.frame within your function:

```
 mods <- do(group_by(it,ind),function(x)
        data.frame(it=unique(as.character(x$ind)),val=min(x$var1)))
```

Then :

```
do.call(rbind,mods)
  it val
1  a   1
2  b   3
3  c   5
```

#### EDIT

```
 mods <- do(group_by(it,ind),
      function(x) setNames(list(min(x$var1)),unique(as.character(x$ind))))

unlist(mods,rec=FALSE)
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 3

$c
[1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get the list, since element of list theoretically can be any R object, which in general cannot be easily put to data.frame.

Comment: so change `data.frame` to `list`... Plus your example has the data originating from a data frame

Comment: @mpiktas see my edit. Of course a list is theoretically can be any R object, but in practice it is  hard to create a list of different elements lengths using a  group by action.