# dplyr: How to apply do() on result of group_by?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to use dplyr to group a table by one column, then apply a function to the set of values in the second column of each group.

For instance, in the code example below, I'd like to return all of the 2-item combinations of foods eaten by each person. I cannot figure out how to properly supply the function with the proper column (foods) in the `do()` function.

```
library(dplyr)

person = c( 'Grace', 'Grace', 'Grace', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'Rob' )
foods   = c( 'apple', 'banana', 'cucumber', 'spaghetti', 'cucumber', 'banana' )
eaten  = data.frame(person, foods)

by_person = group_by(eaten, person)

# How to do this?
do( by_person, combn( x = foods, m = 2 ) )
```

Note that the example code in `?do` fails on my machine

```
mods <- do(carriers, failwith(NULL, lm), formula = ArrDelay ~ date)
```

Comment: After mucking around I saw that this question was re-asked and answered given evolution of `dplyr` https://stackoverflow.com/q/26336180/8400969

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let us define `eaten` like this:

```
eaten <- data.frame(person, foods, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**1)** Then try this:

```
eaten %.% group_by(person) %.% do(function(x) combn(x$foods, m = 2))
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]     [,2]       [,3]      
[1,] "apple"  "apple"    "banana"  
[2,] "banana" "cucumber" "cucumber"

[[2]]
     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]      
[1,] "spaghetti" "spaghetti" "cucumber"
[2,] "cucumber"  "banana"    "banana"
```

**2)** To be able to do something near to what @Hadley describes in the comments without waiting for a future version of dplyr try this where `do2` is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991168/assigning-names-to-the-list-output-of-dplyr-do-operation/21993111#21993111):

```
library(gsubfn)
eaten %.% group_by(person) %.% fn$do2(~ combn(.$foods, m = 2))
```

giving:

```
$Grace
     [,1]     [,2]       [,3]      
[1,] "apple"  "apple"    "banana"  
[2,] "banana" "cucumber" "cucumber"

$Rob
     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]      
[1,] "spaghetti" "spaghetti" "cucumber"
[2,] "cucumber"  "banana"    "banana"
```

*Note:* The last line of the question giving the code in the help file also fails for me.  This variation of it works for me:  `do(jan, lm, formula = ArrDelay ~ date)` .

Comment: In a future version of dplyr you'll be able to do something more like `do(combn(.$foods, m = 2))` and the components will automatically with useful names.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful solution! Minor typo in stringsAsFactors in the first line.

Comment: introduced a new one this time :)

Comment: I think `dplyr` has changed since this answer (#1) was created. One of those changes was going from `%.%` to `%>%`. I fiddled a bit, and the following code produced a tibble with basically the desired output, I think: `eaten %>% group_by(person) %>% do(k=combn(.$foods, m = 2))` Here, k is the column in the tibble where each element is a matrix, where each column has two unique food types possibly eaten by that person, and there are three columns for the three unique pairs.

Comment: As noted above as well, this was re-visited in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26336180/8400969