# dplyr do() without dot pronoun?

Tags: r, dplyr

In `dplyr::do()`, is there a way to access variables in the context of `.data` as with other dplyr functions? For instance, say I have a data frame:

```
> dd <- data.frame(a=1:5)
```

`mutate()`, as well as other functions, works so that expressions are evaluated in the context of the data frame:

```
> mutate(dd,a2=a*2)
  a a2
1 1  2
2 2  4
3 3  6
4 4  8
5 5 10
```

But not `do`:

```
> do(dd,data.frame(a2=a[1:2]*2))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found
```

I can accomplish my objective using `with()` and the dot pronoun:

```
> do(dd,with(.,data.frame(a2=a[1:2]*2)))
  a2
1  2
2  4
```

I am also not sure why this doesn't work:

```
> do(dd,function(X) data.frame(a2=X$a[1:2]*2))
Error: Result must be a data frame
```

Questions:

1. Is there logic to why this behavior (scope) is different from
   `mutate`, `select`, etc.
2. Is there an elegant solution or I have
   to keep using `with()` if I don't want to keep using
   `.$variablename` in the expression?
3. Why doesn't the anonymous
   function work? Seems like it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182442/dplyr-how-to-apply-do-on-result-of-group-by) but not sure why my
   case is different.

Answer (score 3):

1. `mutate`, `select`, etc are specialised functions designed to have the data argument first which work with piping of `magrittr` and help with non-standard evaluation. `do` is a more general function which can not make the same assumptions.
2. It depends on what you are trying to do. If you use a function with non-standard evaluation, you will only need to provide the . once.

For example:

```
do(dd, transform(.,a2=a*2)[1:2,]["a2"])
  a2
1  2
2  4
```

But it is no better than `with` really. The best code golf would be:

```
do(dd, data.frame(a2=.$a[1:2]*2))
  a2
1  2
2  4
```

But it depends on how often you want to refer to the original data.frame. You may find it easier and more readable to use the specialsed functions with piping for this task.

3. You need to call the anonymous function otherwise it is just returning the function definition.

Like so:

```
do(dd,{function(X) data.frame(a2=X$a[1:2]*2)}(.))
  a2
1  2
2  4
```