# using variable column names in dplyr (do)

Tags: r, variables, dplyr

I have the following example data

```
d.1 = data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3), date=c(2001,2002,2001,2001,2003), measure=c(1:5))
d.2 = data.frame(id=c(1,2,2,3,3), date=c(2001,2002,2003,2002,2008), measure=c(1:5))
d = merge(d.1,d.2, all=T, by="id")
```

`d.1` and `d.2` are two kinds of measurements and I need one of each measurements per `id`. The measurements should be as close to each other as possible. I can do that with `dplyr` by

```
require(dplyr)
d = d %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    do(.[which.min(abs(.$date.x-.$date.y)),])
```

The question is how i can use `dplyr` if the names of the date columns are saved in a variable like `name.x="date.x"` and `name.y="date.y"` because i can't use

```
...
do(.[which.min(abs(.[, name.x]-.[, name.y])),])
....
```

I tried to find anaother solution using `eval`, `as.symbol` ans stuff like that but i couldn't figure out a solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d$date.x` returns a vector while `d[, name.x]` returns a data.frame, which does not work when passed inside your function. So simply change the way you access this column to `d[[name.x]]` and it will work:

```
d %>% group_by(id) %>% do(.[which.min(abs(.[[name.x]] -.[[name.y]])),])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 0.4 (which was released just after this question was answered), `dplyr`  has included standard evaluation version `do_`, which in theory should be easier to program with than the NSE version.

You could use it similarly:

```
interp <- lazyeval::interp
d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  do_(interp(~ .[which.min(abs(.$x - .$y)), ],
             x = as.name(name.x), y = as.name(name.y)))
```

I'm not sure it's any easier to read or write than the NSE version. For the other verbs, 
[code can remain concise](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) while also programmatically accessing names.

For `do_`, however, one must use the dot pronoun to access column names [e.g. as discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212734/dplyr-do-without-dot-pronoun). As a consequence, I think, you always need to use `interp` with `do_`. This makes the code more verbose than the NSE version in the earlier answer.