# How to use coef() on output of do() from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lm

My question is *almost* answered in [dplyr 0.3.0.9000 how to use do() correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336180/dplyr-0-3-0-9000-how-to-use-do-correctly), but not quite.

I have some data that looks like this:

```
> head(myData)
   Sequence Index  xSamples ySamples
6         0     5 0.3316187 3.244171
7         0     6 1.5131778 2.719893
8         0     7 1.9088933 3.122991
9         0     8 2.7940244 3.616815
10        0     9 3.6500311 3.519641
```

The Sequence actually ranges from 0 to 9999. Within each Sequence both the xSamples and the ySamples should be linear with respect to Index. The plan is to group myData by Sequence and then use `lm()` via `do()` on each group. The code goes something like this (lifted shamelessly from the help):

```
library(dplyr)
myData_by_sequence <- group_by(myData, Sequence)
models <- myData_by_sequence %>% do(mod = lm(xSamples ~ Index, data = .))
```

This works, but the result I get is this . . .

```
> head(models)
Source: local data frame [10000 x 2]

  Sequence     mod
1        0 <S3:lm>
2        1 <S3:lm>
3        2 <S3:lm>
4        3 <S3:lm>
5        4 <S3:lm>
6        5 <S3:lm>
```

. . . and the data I want is stuck in that second column. I have a working `plyr` solution which goes like this . . .

```
models <- dlply(myData, "Sequence", function(df) lm(xSamples ~ Index, data = df))
xresult <- ldply(models, coef)
```

. . . and this gives me the results broken out into a data frame thanks to `coef()`. The catch is I can't mix dplyr (which I typically use and love) with plyr, and I can't seem to get `coef()` working with that second column from the dplyr output.

I've tried a few other approaches such as trying the `coef()` and `lm()` steps together, and I can break out the second column into a list of linear models, but I can't use `do()` on a list.

I really feel like there is something obvious I'm missing here. R is definitely *not* my primary language. Any help would be appreciated.

*edit*
Have tried . . .

```
result <-
    rects %>% 
    group_by(Sequence) %>% 
    do(data.frame(Coef = coef(lm(xSamples ~ Frame, data = .))))
```

. . . and get something very close, but with the coefficients stacked in the same column:

```
  Sequence       Coef
1        0 -5.0189823
2        0  1.0004240
3        1 -4.9411745
4        1  0.9981858
```

Comment: Try `myData %>% group_by(Sequence) %>% do(data.frame(Coef = coef(lm(xSamples~Index, data=.))))`

Comment: Thanks, your reply is good and I can work with the result, though the result is I have the coefficients arranged linearly instead of in columns (so the rows are alternating intercept, index). Appreciate the quick answer!

Comment: I was working with your head data.  It would be better to provide a little more comprehensive example with the expected output.

Comment: Try `myData %>% group_by(Sequence) %>% do(data.frame(Coef = as.list(coef(lm(xSamples~Index, data=.)))))`

Comment: In the previous code, it was all stacked in a single column 'Coef'.  I think by using `as.list`, it will be two columns, is that your expected result?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I can see I need to figure out this data type stuff in R a bit better. I find it a lot more opaque than Java or C++.

Comment: It seems to be slower than ldply which surprises me. Are there alternatives? I guess I could just loop, but that doesn't seem to be the R way.

Comment: Have you tried the `data.table` option.  It should be fast

Comment: @akrun I'd love to see the `data.table` in action:)

Comment: @Khashaa Updated with a possible option

Comment: I used to use data.table but everyone else I knew was using dplyr so I moved away. I used to use data.table and loops, probably related to my C/Java upbringing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr) 
myData %>%
      group_by(Sequence) %>%
      do(data.frame(setNames(as.list(coef(lm(xSamples~Index, data=.))),
                 c('Intercept', 'Index')))
#    Sequence Intercept     Index
#1        0 -3.502821 0.7917671
#2        1  3.071611 0.3226020
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(myData)[, as.list(coef(lm(xSamples~Index))) , by = Sequence]
 #   Sequence (Intercept)     Index
 #1:        0   -3.502821 0.7917671
 #2:        1    3.071611 0.3226020
```

#### data

```
 myData <- structure(list(Sequence = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
 1L, 1L), Index = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 10L),
 xSamples = c(0.3316187, 
 1.5131778, 1.9088933, 2.7940244, 3.6500311, 7.3316187, 4.5131778, 
 9.9088933, 3.7940244, 4.6500311), ySamples = c(3.244171, 2.719893, 
 3.122991, 3.616815, 3.519641, 3.244171, 8.719893, 5.122991, 7.616815, 
 5.519641)), .Names = c("Sequence", "Index", "xSamples", "ySamples"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! One of my versions was almost this but without the right type conversions.

Comment: Just curious: Suppose you wanted to keep the object with the lms. How would you then extract the coefficients?

Comment: @FelipeGerard  The `object` is a `list` column (if you are using only the `lm`.  You can use `lapply/sapply` to extract the list elements

Comment: I should have tried that. I was trying to keep things in dplyr, I guess just because I thought it should all be nicer.