# Anonymous function with dplyr::do - using results from rle to filter data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have time series data grouped by subject ('id'), which stay on certain 'site' and have a certain 'stage' in each 'time' step.

Sometimes subjects switch from one site to another, and possibly back again. If individuals switch site **back and forth** (e.g. from site 'a' to site 'b', and then back to site 'a') *and* if there is only **one registration on the middle site** (in a transition a-b-a, then site 'b' would here be considered a 'middle site') *and* the individual is in a **certain stage** (here, stage = 2) **at the middle site**, then I wish to **remove** the registration at this time step.

My dummy data consists of four subjects. Three of them (subject 1-3) have moved from site a to b, and then back to site b, and one has moved from a to b.

The first two subjects both have a single registration on the middle site. Subject 1 is in stage 1 on the middle site and I wish to keep that registration. Subject 2 on the other hand is in stage 2 on the middle site and this registration should be removed. Subject 3, has also moved back and forth between a and b. However, although it is in stage 2 on the middle site b, it has *two* registrations there and both registrations are kept. Subject 4 has moved from site a to b, but not back again. Thus, although it is in stage 2 on site b, the registration on site b is not a 'middle site' and should be kept.

The data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4),
                     time = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L),
                     site = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b"),
                     stage = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2)),
                     .Names = c("id", "time", "site", "stage"),
                row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

df

#    id time site stage
# 1   1    1    a     1
# 2   1    2    b     1 <~~ A single middle registration on site 2
# 3   1    3    a     1     However, the individual is in stage 1: -> keep 

# 4   2    1    a     1
# 5   2    2    b     2 <~~ A single middle registration on site 2 with stage 2: -> remove
# 6   2    3    a     1

# 7   3    1    a     1
# 8   3    2    b     2 <~~ Two middle registrations with stage 2: -> keep both rows 
# 9   3    3    b     2 <~~
# 10  3    4    a     1

# 11  4    1    a     1 
# 12  4    2    b     2 <~~ A single registration on site 2 with stage 2,
#                            but it is not in between two sites: -> keep
```

Thus, in the test data, it is only the registration at time = 2 for id = 2 which should be removed.

Previously, I have used `plyr::ddply` and result from `rle` to solve the problem:

For each individual, calculate run lengths of site (`rle(x$site)`)
**If**:
 - back and forth between sites (e.g. from a to b, and back to a)
   (`length(r$values) > 2`) **&**
 - only one registration on middle site (`r$lengths[2] == 1`) **&**
 - stage on middle site is 2 (`x$stage[x$site == r$values[2]][1] == 2`)
**Then**: remove registration on middle site `x[!(x$site == r$values[2]), ]`)

```
library(plyr)

ddply(df, .(id), function(x){
  r <- rle(x$site)
  if(length(r$values) > 2 & r$lengths[2] == 1 & x$stage[x$site == r$values[2]][1] == 2){
    x[x$site != r$values[2], ]
  } else x
})

#    id time site stage
# 1   1    1    a     1
# 2   1    2    b     1
# 3   1    3    a     1

# 4   2    1    a     1 <~~ the single middle site with stage = 2 at time 2 is removed
# 5   2    3    a     1 <~~

# 6   3    1    a     1
# 7   3    2    b     2
# 8   3    3    b     2
# 9   3    4    a     1

# 10  4    1    a     1
# 11  4    2    b     2

detach("package:plyr")
```

Now I have some trouble getting this right in `dplyr`. I found some relevant posts on SO (e.g. [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182442/dplyr-how-to-apply-do-on-result-of-group-by/22182914#22182914) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376765/dplyrdo-requires-named-function)), and on github ([**this**](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/574) and [**this**](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/418)), but I have trouble to adapt them to my needs. Here are some desperate attempts:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do((function(x){
    r = rle(x$site)
    if(length(r$values) > 2 & r$lengths[2] == 1 & df$stage[df$site == r$values[2]][1] == 2){
    filter(x, x$site != r$values[2])
  } else x
})(.))
# desired row is not removed

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(function(x){
    r = rle(x$site)
    if(length(r$values) > 2 & r$lengths[2] == 1 & df$stage[df$site == r$values[2]][1] == 2){
      x[!(x$site == r$values[2]), ]
    } else x
  })
# Error: Results are not data frames at positions: 1, 2, 3
```

This attempt happens to work (gives same result as `ddply` above), but is very far from elegant, and I doubt it's 'the right way':

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(r = rle(.$site)) %>%  
  do(data.frame(id = .$id,
                len = length(.$r$values),
                site = .$r$values[2],
                len2 = .$r$lengths[2])) %>%
  filter(len == 3, len2 == 1) %>%
  select(-len) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = c("id", "site")) %>%
  filter(!(len2 %in% 1 & stage == 2)) %>%
  select(-len2)
```

How to `do` this properly? WWHWD?

Comment: I wanted to benchmark the approaches but noticed that your last approach doesn't work (at least on my machine) when I use your input df. The error is in the `do(r = rle(.$site))` and reads: "Error in rle(.$site) : 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type".

Comment: @beginneR, It seems like you have 'site' as `factor`, not as `character` (I have `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in my `option`). I `dput` df instead. I bet your method is faster than my convoluted attempt...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I fully understood the logic behind your code, but this might be another way to get to the same result, perhaps with some modifications if needed:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(abs(c(1, diff(as.numeric(site))))), add = TRUE) %>%
  filter(!(grp == 2 & n() == 1 & stage == 2))

#Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
#Groups: id, grp
#
#  id time site stage grp
#1  1    1    a     1   1
#2  1    2    b     1   2
#3  1    3    a     1   3
#4  2    1    a     1   1     <~~ row in between 
#5  2    3    a     1   3     <~~ was removed
#6  3    1    a     1   1
#7  3    2    b     2   2
#8  3    3    b     2   2
#9  3    4    a     1   3
```

This approach assumes that the "middle group" is always the second "grp".

---

Might be even nicer to create a function - which I'm gonna call `intergroup()` since it creates groups inside the grouped data, and use that:

```
intergroup <- function(var, start = 1) {
  cumsum(abs(c(start, diff(as.numeric(as.factor(var))))))
}

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  group_by(grp = intergroup(site), add = TRUE) %>%
  filter(!(grp == 2 & n() == 1 & stage == 2))
```

---

Edit after OP question update.

Try the following adjusted code for the adjusted problem:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(z = lag(site, 1) != lead(site, 1)) %>%   # check if site before and after are not the same
  group_by(grp = intergroup(site), add = TRUE) %>%
  filter(!(grp == 2 & n() == 1 & stage == 2 & !is.na(z))) %>%  # check for NA in z
  ungroup() %>% select(-c(z, grp))  

#Source: local data frame [11 x 4]
#
#   id time site stage
#1   1    1    a     1
#2   1    2    b     1
#3   1    3    a     1
#4   2    1    a     1
#5   2    3    a     1
#6   3    1    a     1
#7   3    2    b     2
#8   3    3    b     2
#9   3    4    a     1
#10  4    1    a     1
#11  4    2    b     2    <~~ row is kept
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The `cumsum` grouping variable was definitely more elegant than my `rle` version (+1).

Comment: @Henrik, sure thing, thanks for letting me know. Btw, maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27202707/3521006) by akrun is also interesting for you, since he uses rle in a dplyr chain, not in `do`, though.

Comment: In my post I wrote "_Sometimes_ subjects switch from one site to another, and _possibly_ back again". It was a mistake from my side not to include a test case with an individual which _not_ moves back and forth from the start. I have updated my data (added id 4). I notice that your answer needs to be adjusted to handle such 'non-middle' cases. Sorry for not providing this case from the very start.

Comment: @Henrik, it's a little unclear how exactly those middle cases are defined. A simple solution for the adjusted case might be `filter(!(grp == 2 & n() == 1 & stage == 2) | n_distinct(grp) <= 2)` but I'm not sure whether that is enough for your requirements (e.g. when there is no "middle case": does that mean there are only 1 or 2 different grp entries at maximum or how is the definition?)

Comment: @Henrik, I updated my answer. Does that fulfill the requirements? It's based on the fact that you only want to remove rows where there is only a single middle case row and, hence, you can just check the lagging and leading rows for equality.

Comment: Thanks again for taking your time. I learned several nice tricks from your answer. Very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `rle` alternative which doesn't rely on `do`. The code was inspired by [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202593/subsetting-df-with-repeated-sequences/27202707#27202707) by @akrun (posted right after my question; thanks to @beginneR for the heads up).

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(site_idx = with(rle(site),
                           rep(x = seq_along(lengths), times = lengths))) %>%
  filter(!(n_distinct(site_idx) > 2 & sum(site_idx == 2) == 1 &
           site_idx == 2 & stage == 2)) %>%
  select(-site_idx)

#    id time site stage
# 1   1    1    a     1
# 2   1    2    b     1
# 3   1    3    a     1
# 4   2    1    a     1 <~~ the single middle site with stage = 2 at time 2 has been removed
# 5   2    3    a     1 <~~
# 6   3    1    a     1
# 7   3    2    b     2
# 8   3    3    b     2
# 9   3    4    a     1
# 10  4    1    a     1
# 11  4    2    b     2
```

Comment: I think you have one `group_by` too many - or what is the second supposed to do? (I think you only need mutate here and could then remove the third, group_by, no?)