# error "no applicable method for 'regroup' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')""

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I am new to r I have a problem i.e to find the network of user(uID) and network of articles(faID) from a data frame called w2 like

```
faID      uID
 1        1256
 1        54789
 1        547821
 2        3258
 2        4521
 2        4528
 3        98745
 3        1256
 3        3258
 3        2145
```

this is just a example I have over 2000 articles what I want to make a relationship between users based on articles in a data frame format e.g.
**##for article one##**

```
1258  54789
1258  547821
54789 547821
```

**##similarly for article 2##**

```
3258  4521
3258  4528
4528  4521
```

some of the other information are

dput(head(w2,)) 
structure(list(faID=c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L),uID=c(20909L,6661L,1591L,28065L,42783L,3113L)),   .Names=c("faID","uID"),row.names=c(7L,9L,10L,12L,14L,16L),class=data.frame")

```
dim(w2) 
[1] 364323 2
```

I am using the code advised by one of the volunteer

### error appears at <<<>>"Error in UseMethod("regroup") :

no applicable method for 'regroup' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')") ##

```
library(dplyr)
edges<-tbl_df(w2) %>% 
group_by(w2$faID) %>% 
do({    
tmp <-combn(sort(.$user),m =2)
data.frame(a=tmp[1,],b=tmp[2,],stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
 })%>%
 ungroup 
}
```

any suggestion will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not yet implemented in `dplyr` from reading [Assigning names to the list output of dplyr do operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991168/assigning-names-to-the-list-output-of-dplyr-do-operation/21993111#21993111)

You may do:

```
library(gsubfn)
library(dplyr)
w2%>% 
group_by(faID) %>%
fn$do2(~combn(.$uID, m=2)) #`do2` from the link

#    $`1`
#      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
#[1,]  1256   1256  54789
#[2,] 54789 547821 547821

#   $`2`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] 3258 3258 4521
#[2,] 4521 4528 4528

#  $`3`
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,] 98745 98745 98745 1256 1256 3258
# [2,]  1256  3258  2145 3258 2145 2145
```

#### data

```
w2 <- structure(list(faID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), uID = c(1256L, 54789L, 547821L, 3258L, 4521L, 4528L, 98745L, 
1256L, 3258L, 2145L)), .Names = c("faID", "uID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

#### Update

It would be possible to do:

```
res <- w2 %>% 
group_by(faID) %>% 
do({data.frame(
     combN=paste(apply(combn(sort(.$uID), m=2),2,paste,collapse=" "),
    collapse=", "), stringsAsFactors=F)})

res
#   faID                                                               combN
# 1    1                               1256 54789, 1256 547821, 54789 547821
# 2    2                                     3258 4521, 3258 4528, 4521 4528
# 3    3 1256 2145, 1256 3258, 1256 98745, 2145 3258, 2145 98745, 3258 98745

library(data.table)
```

Use `cSplit` from https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733

```
cSplit(cSplit(res, "combN", ", ", "long"),"combN", " ")
#     faID combN_1 combN_2
#  1:    1    1256   54789
#  2:    1    1256  547821
#  3:    1   54789  547821
#  4:    2    3258    4521
#  5:    2    3258    4528
#  6:    2    4521    4528
#  7:    3    1256    2145
#  8:    3    1256    3258
#  9:    3    1256   98745
# 10:    3    2145    3258
# 11:    3    2145   98745
# 12:    3    3258   98745
```

Comment: I have copy paste the code in link and then apply the above code it gives me this error "error in eval(expr,envir,enclos) : object fn not found

Comment: @user3841811.  If I don't load the `library(gsubfn)`, I will get the error you mentioned.

Comment: @user3841811.  With the same dataset, I don't have any errors.  If you can show the data using `dput` on a smaller dataset (10-20 rows) that shows the error, I will try.

Comment: actually the data above is just a subset of the whole data set some of the information are dput(head(w2,)) structure(list(faID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), uID = c(20909L, 6661L, 1591L, 28065L, 42783L, 3113L)), .Names = c("faID", "uID" ), row.names = c(7L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @user3841811.  Using my second approach.  I am getting the result. res$combN
[1] "1591 3113, 1591 6661, 1591 20909, 1591 28065, 1591 42783, 3113 6661, 3113 20909, 3113 28065, 3113 42783, 6661 20909, 6661 28065,  6661 42783, 20909 28065, 20909 42783, 28065 42783".  Using gsubfn, also I get the results. `1`
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5] [,6]  [,7]  [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,] 20909 20909 20909 20909 20909 6661  6661  6661 6661  1591  1591  1591
[2,]  6661  1591 28065 42783  3113 1591 28065 42783 3113 28065 42....

Comment: yes 2nd approach works but the groups(networked users) are made in a single cell where i want them to be in a separate cell both ID's for finding the centralities .

Comment: `user3841811`. I got both the methods working.  I am using R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit);package versions: gsubfn_0.6-5: dplyr_0.2

Comment: in your your 2nd method you can see the results are in one cell e.e for faid =1 1256and 54789 are in one cell similarly 1256 and 547821 are in one cell .any recommendations how to separate them in two different cells.

Comment: `user3841811`. Yes, as I mentioned before, and found in the comments from the link, there are some limitations at present (may be I am wrong)..

Comment: the approach  to some extent is according to my requirement but only thing I want is to separate the user id's into two cells

Comment: @user3841811. I just updated the code.  Now, the user ids' are separated into two columns.